# Automatically close window after timeout

Tags: php, javascript

I know php is server-side, but is there a way to make this window close after 3 seconds?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />
<?php 
$contact_message=$_POST['message'];
$errpage = $_POST['frompage'];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$message = "$contact_message -SENT FROM THIS IP: $ip";
mail("maxgee@me.com", "$Error Reported on: $errpage", $message);
echo "We have documented the web address of the problem and thank you for helping us    improve our site!"
?>
```

Comment: if anything, you'd be looking at javascript to attempt achieve what you want.

Comment: @anditpainsme Do you know a script that would do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout("window.close();", 3000);</script>
```

Comment: Fair enough, @pst. `setTimeout( function() { window.close(); }, 3000);` is better coding style.

Comment: Neither sample code is working when I tried on Firefox or Safari.  On Chrome it said "server error 500".  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple - just write the JavaScript code in PHP with echo in the place where you want to move out from itself, such as:

```
<?php

    echo '<script> window.setTimeout("window.close()", 1000); </script>';

?>
```

It will definitely work.

Answer (score -1):

It may seems a little weird if a page I am watching suddenly be closed.

Comment: It is gonna be used in a popup window and after submit the form it will close